# Web page loading over and over on java script re-direct for mobile/android devices

Tags: javascript, redirect, infinite-loop

Hi I am trying to redirect my homepage [www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk](http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk) to a different web page when opened with a mobile device such as an Ipad, IPhone, Android etc.. I have managed to acheive this using a neat java script on my homepage (see script below)

```
<script language=javascript>
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry/i)))
{
location.replace("http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html");
}
</script>
```

but when the alternative web page is opened it just keeps inifinitely reloading thepage over and over??

I have tried using .htaccess to do this but just kept getting 'The page has too many server redirects' error and couldn't get it to work.

I would appreciate it if someone could have a look at the java script and see if I have done anything wrong.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is also in the `http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html` page, so when it is opened in a mobile browser, the redirect is triggered again and again.

Related: As there are increasingly different kinds of devices out there, the simple distinction between "Desktop" and "Mobile" versions does not make so much sense. You might want to get into [Responsive Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) instead:

> Responsive web design (often abbreviated to RWD) is an approach to web
>   design in which a site is crafted to provide an optimal viewing
>   experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing,
>   panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from desktop
>   computer monitors to mobile phones).

Comment: Wow so simple..!! lol thanks for checking it out, it was driving me nuts :D yes I agree I am not a professional web designer and when I get the time I will create a much more user friendly redirect for certain devices, I am just very short on time and need to get this site working for the time being. Thanks again pixelistik :)